# Trimming the utcnow() function

Tags: flow

Using Flow recurrence on SharePoint List Items, I'm able to send emails based on **utcnow()** expression in the flow. But the expression brings the whole timestamp. I would like to know if we can trim the expression to only give date as result, removing the time from the expression.
Current condition:

> if [current date] Greater than or Equal to [utcnow()]
>   
>  The above expression looks for all the items in the list that are equal to the whole date time stamp.

Would like to know if we can trim the expression to compare only date field excluding time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Look at the official documentation about [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) in Flow

Comment: I used this today and we are no longer needed `@`. And its `utcNow` (N capital). `formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')` will work.